# Hash, cookie in browser and storage in database not working

Tags: php

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvXgsouIzVg&t=15310s about how to build a register form with database connection. For some reason storing the Hash Cookie in the browser and in the database doesn't work for me, even with the remember option include in the code and still it's like it doesn't do anything.

The remember option starts at 3:26:00 after that i did everything like he shows but at some point the Cookie hash doesn't show in my browser

I don't know what i'm doing wrong so maybe someone can point it out for me.

I know that the tutorial is outdated but in some way i like the way the guy explain what he is doing, i'm a noob at this but had to make the start at some point.

I had some problems whit the Hash::make function since PHP 7.2.2 works different this days, but i solved that in a different way as the tutorial shows and now i think i'm having problems whit the Hash.php file.

A other thing that i did was that i installed WORDPRESS a week a go and had to make some privileges changes in the database, could this be the reason why it's not working properly???, even the case that i'm not using the tables generated by WORDPRESS in the database but still working on the same table created by following the tutorial

This is the code on the Config.php file

```
<?php
class Config {
    public static function get($path = null) {
        if($path) {
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $bit) {
                if(isset($config[$bit])) {
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }

            return $config;
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

This is the code on Cookie.php file

```
<?php
class Cookie {
    public static function exists($name) {
        return (isset($_COOKIE[$name])) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        return $_COOKIE[$name];
    }

    public static function put($name, $value, $expiry) {
        if(setcookie($name, $value, time() + $expiry, '/')) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function delete($name) {
        self::put($name, '', time() -1);
    }
}
```

This is the code on DB.php file

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error =false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'),  Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
          self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)) {
                foreach($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

          if($this->_query->execute()) {
              $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
              $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
          } else {
                $this->_error = true;
          }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if(count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

            $field      =$where[0];
            $operator   =$where[1];
            $value      =$where[2];

            if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);

    }

    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE *', $table, $where);
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $values = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $values .='?';
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .=', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql= "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
        $set = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = ($id)";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    Public function first() {
        return $this->results()[0];
    }

    public function error() {
        return $this->_error;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```

This is the code on the Hash.php file

```
<?php
class Hash {

    public static function make($string, $salt = '') {
        return hash('sha256', $string . $salt);
    }

    public static function salt($length) {
        #return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
        return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", $length)), 0, $length);
    }

    public static function unique() {
        return self::make(uniqid());
    }
}
```

This is the code on the Input.php file

```
 <?php
class Input {
    public static function exists($type = 'post') {
        switch($type) {
            case 'post':
                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
            break;
            case 'get':
                return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
            break;
            default:
                return false;
            break;
        }
    }

    public static function get($item) {
        if(isset($_POST[$item])) {
            return $_POST[$item];
        } else if(isset($_GET[$item])) {
            return $_GET[$item];
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

This is the code on the Redirect.php file

```
<?php
class Redirect {
  public static function to($location = null) {
      if($location) {
          if(is_numeric($location)) {
              switch($location) {
                  case 404:
                      header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
                      include 'includes/errors/404.php';
                      exit();
                  break;
              }
          }
          header('Location:' . $location);
          exit();
      }
  }
}
```

This is the code on the Session.php file

```
<?php
class Redirect {
  public static function to($location = null) {
      if($location) {
          if(is_numeric($location)) {
              switch($location) {
                  case 404:
                      header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
                      include 'includes/errors/404.php';
                      exit();
                  break;
              }
          }
          header('Location:' . $location);
          exit();
      }
  }
}
```

This is the code on the Token.php file

```
<?php
class Token {
    public static function generate() {
        return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), md5(uniqid()));
    }

    public static function check($token) {
        $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

        if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
            Session::delete($tokenName);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the code on the User.php file

```
<?php
class User {
    private $_db,
            $_data,
            $_sessionName,
            $_cookieName,
            $_isLoggedIn;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
        $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

        if(!$user) {
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                if($this->find($user)) {
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
                } else {
                    // process Logout
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->find($user);
        }

    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account.');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if($user) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

                if($remember) {
                    $hash = Hash::unique();
                    $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

                    if(!$hashCheck->count()) {
                        $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                            'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                            'hash' => $hash
                        ));
                    } else {
                        $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                    }

                    Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function logout() {
        Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
    }

    public function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
        return $this->_isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

This is the code on the Validate.php file

```
<?php
class Validate {
    private $_passed = false,
            $_errors = array(),
            $_db =  null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    Public function check($source, $items = array()) {
        foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
            foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

                $value = trim($source[$item]);
                $item = escape($item);

                if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                    $this->addError("{$item} is required");
                } else if(!empty($value)){
                    switch($rule) {
                        case 'min':
                            if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                                $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimun of {$rule_value} vcharacters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'max':
                            if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                                $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'matches':
                            if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                                $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}");
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'unique':
                            $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
                            if($check->count()) {
                                $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        if(empty($this->_errors)) {
            $this->_passed = true;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    private function addError($error) {
        $this->_errors[] = $error;
    }

    public function errors() {
        return $this->_errors;
    }

    public function passed() {
        return $this->_passed;
    }
}
```

This is the code on the init.php file

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '******',
        'password' => '******',
        'db' => 'users-pass'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
      'cookie_name' => 'hash',
      'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';

if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && !Session::exists(Config::get('session/session_name'))) {
    echo 'User asked to be remembered';
}
```

This is the code on the sanitize.php file

```
<?php
function escape($string){
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

This is the code on the index.php file

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Session::exists('home')) {
    echo '<p>' . Session::flash('home') . '</p>';
}

 $user = new User();
if($user->isLoggedIn()) {
?>
    <p>Hello <a href="#"><?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?></a>!</p>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
    </ul>

<?php
} else {
    echo '<p>You need to <a href="login.php">log in</a> or <a href="register.php">register</a></p>';
}
```

This is the code on login.php file

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username'  => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $remember = (Input::get('remeber') === 'on') ? true : false;
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);

            if($login) {
                Redirect::to('index.php');
            } else {
                echo '<p>Sorry, logging in failed.</p>';
            }

          } else {
              foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                  echo $error, '<br>';
              }
          }

    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="remember">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

This is the code on logout.php file

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = new User();
$user->logout();

Redirect::to('index.php');
```

This is the code on register.php file

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 20,
                'unique' => 'users'
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 6
            ),
            'password_again' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'matches' => 'password'
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            )
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {

                $user->create(array(
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'name' => Input::get('name'),
                    'joined'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1
                ));

                Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now log in!');
                Redirect::to('index.php');

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password_again">Enter your password again</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Enter your name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('name')); ?>" id="name">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Any help?

Comment: What happens with the code? There is a lot of code here. You also should use parameterized everywhere. `DELETE *` is incorrect, you delete a whole row, not columns so the `*` shouldnt be there.

Comment: this is the tutorial 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvXgsouIzVg&t=15310s

 at 3:38:30 the hash doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you simplify this to [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have 3 hours to figure out what is suppose to happen.

Comment: There are hundreds of lines of code and i'm pretty sure most of them are not related to your problem. as said by MaxvonHippel, you have to reduce your code to a minimal exampe so it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: @MaxvonHippel that is the code

Comment: @CROZET i would like to do that but then again i think that i would leave some important info out since i don't know what i can remove and what i have to keep

Comment: Randy, the process of making a MCVE will show you what you need and what you don't.  Start with nothing, and add code in until you get the error.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel 

(Solved)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a (m) in the code on the login.php file

```
$remember = (Input::get('**remeber**') === 'on') ? true : false;
$login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);
```

solved by changing it to:

```
$remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false;
$login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember);
```

Thanks anyway.